# redirect some domains to https and some to http in IIS

Tags: redirect, iis, iis-10

I redirect all requests to https with below rule but now I want to prevent redirection for some subdomains.

I redirected test.com to https://test.com, sub.test.com to https://sub.test.com
But I don't want sub2.sub.test.com to be redirected.

```
 <rule name="https2" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Temporary" />
            </rule>
```

What should I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try below rule:

```
<rule name="http2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^test.com$|^sub.test.com$" />
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
            </rule>
```

this rule only redirects domain wich set in condition.